# How to calculate occupancy rate per hour?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, difftime

I'm trying to calculate occupancy rate per hour in R. To do that I need the minutes of one meeting (difference in start and end time) and divide it by 60 minutes times 100%.

I have trouble calculating this when the endtime is in a different hour than the start time.

For example:
Meeting is from 12.50 till 13.10, then R says the meeting is 20 minutes (which is true!), but I want to split it per hour. So 10 minutes should be in hour 12.00-13.00 and 10 minutes in 13.00-14.00

```
                Start_Time            End_Time occupied Room_ID
    1  2019-09-02 09:03:00 2019-09-02 10:32:00        1    7820
    2  2019-09-02 10:35:00 2019-09-02 11:06:00        1    7820
    3  2019-09-02 11:29:00 2019-09-02 12:20:00        1    7820
    4  2019-09-02 12:42:00 2019-09-02 13:09:00        1    7820
    5  2019-09-02 14:07:00 2019-09-02 14:22:00        1    7820
    6  2019-09-02 14:22:00 2019-09-02 14:27:00        1    7820
    7  2019-09-02 14:56:00 2019-09-02 15:18:00        1    7820
```

If I use difftime(), it stores 89 minutes in the first row, which I want to divide. What can I do?

Comment: Use `cut(x, breaks = '60 min')` where `x` is your date variable

Comment: You can also look at the package `lubridate` which has many tools to work with dates and time. Here is a nice cheat sheet : https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Using only base R functions on this data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Start_Time = as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-02 09:03:00","2019-09-02 10:35:00","2019-09-02 11:29:00","2019-09-02 12:42:00","2019-09-02 14:07:00","2019-09-02 14:22:00","2019-09-02 14:56:00"),tz = "UTC"),
  End_Time = as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-02 10:32:00","2019-09-02 11:06:00","2019-09-02 12:20:00","2019-09-02 13:09:0","2019-09-02 14:22:00","2019-09-02 14:27:00","2019-09-02 15:18:00"),tz = "UTC"),
  Room_ID = 1)
```

A solution might be:

```
occupancy_rate <- function(data){
  agg <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(data),function(i){
    times <- seq(data$Start_Time[i], data$End_Time[i], by = 60)
    aggregate(list(occ_mins=times),list(date_hour=strftime(times,"%y-%m-%d %H")), length)
  }))
  with(agg,aggregate(list(occ_mins=occ_mins), list(date_hour=date_hour), function(x) sum(x)/60*100))
}
```

Which produces:

```
occupancy_rate(data)
    date_hour occupancy_rate
1 19-09-02 10       95.00000
2 19-09-02 11       96.66667
3 19-09-02 12       63.33333
4 19-09-02 13       65.00000
5 19-09-02 14       16.66667
6 19-09-02 15       43.33333
7 19-09-02 16       31.66667
```

Obviously, if the dataset is larger you might want to look at external libraries like `data.table` or `dplyr`